# Is it possible to change the file name in java code from the Oracle JCA Adapter valves?

Tags: java, oracle, soa, jca

I have implemented a pipeline valve with the SOA Suite 11g file adapter.
Got java code, like this

```
import oracle.tip.pc.services.pipeline.*;

public class MyValve extends AbstractValve {
    public InputStreamContext execute(InputStreamContext context) throws PipelineException, IOException {
        InputStream stream;
        ... // encode contents and write it to stream
        context.setInputStream(stream);
        return context;
    }
}
```

It is used for write operation. Is it possible to change the directory and filename in the *inputStreamContext* or *PipelineContext* within the valve?

There are the *getMessageOriginReference* method in *InputStreamContext* class, which returns a string containing the directory and filename. And *setMessageOriginReference* method, which does not work for me.